# WPF enabling transparency

Tags: wpf, xaml

Going off the how-to from MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-reflection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), I have the following code that displays a reflection right below an element.

How can I enable transparency on the reflection only, so what is behind the window shows through the reflection?

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLViewTests.AboutWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AboutWindow" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Width="400"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Background="Transparent">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="formattedText">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradBrush">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0"
                                  Color="White"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0"
                                  Color="LightSlateGray"></GradientStop>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{StaticResource linearGradBrush}">
        <Button Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="ReturnToPreviousWindow" Background="White">Return</Button>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource formattedText}" x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            Some text here.
        </TextBlock>
        <!-- Reflection visual courtesy of MS How-To at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970263(v=vs.110).aspx -->
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualHeight}"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualWidth}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=HorizontalAlignment}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="None" Visual="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}">
                    <VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1"></ScaleTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform Y="1"></TranslateTransform>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0.0"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="0.5"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.9"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="2.5"></BlurEffect>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear gradient brush has 100% opacity and is applied to the entire stackpanel which contains the element you want transparency on. I reformatted it a bit and split out the stackpanel. Probably needs more work, but this should demonstrate the concept. Note the second gradient brush with a 0.5 (50%) opacity applied to the second stackpanel.

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLViewTests.AboutWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="AboutWindow" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Width="400"
    AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Background="Transparent">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="formattedText">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradBrush">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.0"
                              Color="White"></GradientStop>
            <GradientStop Offset="1.0"
                              Color="LightSlateGray"></GradientStop>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradBrushWithTransparency" Opacity="0.5">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.0"
                              Color="White"></GradientStop>
            <GradientStop Offset="1.0"
                              Color="LightSlateGray"></GradientStop>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{StaticResource linearGradBrushWithTransparency}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{StaticResource linearGradBrush}">
    <Button Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="ReturnToPreviousWindow" Background="White">Return</Button>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource formattedText}" x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        Some text here.
    </TextBlock>
    <!-- Reflection visual courtesy of MS How-To at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970263(v=vs.110).aspx -->
    <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Height="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualHeight}"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualWidth}"
               HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=HorizontalAlignment}"
               Opacity=".5">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="None" Visual="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}">
                <VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1"></ScaleTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="1"></TranslateTransform>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0.0"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="0.5"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.9"></GradientStop>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="2.5"></BlurEffect>
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```